# Date representation in GEDCOM X for calendars other than Gregorian

Tags: gedcom, date

Gedcom X date format specification (https://github.com/FamilySearch/gedcomx/blob/master/specifications/date-format-specification.md) defines the string representation for Gregorian dates. However, I failed to find any similar specification for the other calendars recognized in classical GEDCOM (JULIAN, FRENCH, HEBREW), in the above document or elsewhere. Does such documentation at all exist? If yes, I would be thankful for a hint.

Answer (score 2):

Gedcom X only allows Gregorian dates.

In the Date Format specification that you give the link to, see Section 4 of Calendaring System, where they state:

> "Dates MUST be specified using the proleptic Gregorian calendar."

Comment: Thank you, sorry, cannot upvote (<15 points :-))